# What type should be used for sorted list in Nim?

Tags: nim-lang

Why type infer fails for this line?

```
let sorted = if is_sorted: values else: values.sorted
```

How to fix it?

```
proc min*(values: open_array[float], is_sorted = false): float =
  let sorted = if is_sorted: values else: values.sorted
  values[0]

echo min(@[3.0, 1.0, 2.3])
```

`min` is just a simple example to highlight the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`openArray` can only be used as a parameter and cannot be assigned to a variable with `let`, as the error to your code explicitly says:

`Error: invalid type: 'openArray[float]' for let`

One way to make it compile would be to use a `template` instead of a `proc` (see [this forum post](https://forum.nim-lang.org/t/6478#39963)), but it would fail again when called with an array.

Note that in your case `values` can be an `array` or a `seq` (since it is an `openArray`), while `values.sorted` is always a `seq`.

Two possible ways to fix this.

One is to replace openarray with seq:

```
import algorithm

template min*(values: seq[float], is_sorted = false): float =
  let sorted = if is_sorted: values else: values.sorted
  values[0]

echo min(@[3.0, 1.0, 2.3])
```

Another is to explicitly convert to sequence:

```
import algorithm, sequtils

template min*(values: open_array[float], is_sorted = false): float =
  let sorted = if is_sorted: values.toSeq else: values.sorted
  values[0]

echo min(@[3.0, 1.0, 2.3])
```